# Showing only a single item from the List

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following Model class, it has 5 objects in the list. Rather than showing all of them in a single page, I would like to show first item in the first fragment, second item in the second fragment, and so on.

I am using mvvm pattern.

**RecyclerViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Example.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class RecyclerViewModel
        : MvxViewModel
    {
        private ListItem _selectedItem;

        public RecyclerViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem> {
                new ListItem { Title = "A" },
                new ListItem { Title = "B" },
                new ListItem { Title = "C" },
                new ListItem { Title = "D" },
                new ListItem { Title = "E" }
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ListItem> _items;

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
            }
        }

        public ListItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
            }
        }

        public virtual ICommand ItemSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand<ListItem>(item =>
                {
                    SelectedItem = item;
                });
            }
        }

        private bool _isRefreshing;

        public virtual bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get { return _isRefreshing; }
            set
            {
                _isRefreshing = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsRefreshing);
            }
        }

        public ICommand ReloadCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(async () =>
                {
                    IsRefreshing = true;

                    await ReloadData();

                    IsRefreshing = false;
                });
            }
        }
```

**ExampleViewPagerFragment.cs**

```
namespace Example.Droid.Fragments
{
    [MvxFragment(typeof (MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    [Register("example.droid.fragments.ExampleViewPagerFragment")]
    public class ExampleViewPagerFragment : BaseFragment<ExampleViewPagerViewModel>
    {
        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_example_viewpager;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            if (viewPager != null)
            {
                var fragments = new List<MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
                {
                    new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                        typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                    new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 2", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                        typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                    new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 3", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                        typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                    new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 4", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                        typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                    new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 5", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                        typeof (RecyclerViewModel))
                };
                viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
            }

            var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the current output.

[image]

---

**Update:**

Here is the xmls

**fragmentviewpager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            local:tabGravity="center"
            local:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**recyclerview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsRefreshing; RefreshCommand ReloadCommand">
        <MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_recyclerviewexample"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemSelected" />
    </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show me your view? Maybe you can bind a new property that gets converted to the right item with a custom converter. No need for duplicate viewmodels.

Comment: @PmanAce, I have added xmls as well, refer to Update. That would be awesome if you could able to handle it.

Comment: Here is my project github: https://github.com/texas16/ViewPagerMVVM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your safest bet is probably to have 5 viewmodels?

if you dont want that.. you could make a static class to hold an integer and an array

the integer will be your index for your array.

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static String[] a= {"A","B","C","D","E"};
    public static int index = 0;
}
```

so in your constructor:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem> {
                new ListItem { Title = StaticClass.a[StaticClass.index] }
            };
StaticClass.Index++;
```

Youll have to test it tho. Race conditioning could be a problem i guess.. :)

EDIT:

to avoid going out of bounds you could use

```
Title = StaticClass.a[StaticClass.index < StaticClass.a.Length ? StaticClass.Index : StaticClass.a.Length -1]
```

Comment: I have tested and each page shows the exact same thing which is `StaticClass.a[StaticClass.index]`

Comment: woops! you shouldnt have the " "..
try Title = StaticClass.a[StaticClass.index]

Comment: Thanks Jesper, I have got it fixed. the only piece is missing, index might be out of boundary.

Comment: to make sure it never goes out of bounds:
Title = StaticClass.a[StaticClass.index < StaticClass.a.Length ? StaticClass.Index : StaticClass.a.Length -1]

Comment: And if it works please mark my suggestion as the answer ;)

Comment: I have marked as an answer also upvoted as well. There is a similar question which is related to this one. I would be glad if you have any idea to share http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927221/pass-object-from-viewmodel-to-view

Comment: Wish i could help you with that one. Ive only used xamarin.forms so i havent toyed with that MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: I am using xamarin.android. I only want to have a same number of fragments with staticClass list of array. For example if I have five elements in my staticClass list, then I want to create a five fragments only.

Comment: Alright i think i understood the question better now.. i posted an answer on your other question

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps create a custom binding to pass a parameter to ItemsSource.

Here is an example of a custom binding (Summary) bound to a property in my viewmodel:

```
local:MvxBind="Text SummaryEnum3Int; Summary SummaryEnum3;" />
```

in setup:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("Summary", textView => new SummaryTextViewBinding(textView)));
}
```

and custom binding:

```
public class SummaryTextViewBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    readonly TextView _textView;
    SummaryEnumeration _currentValue;

    public SummaryTextViewBinding(TextView textView) : base(textView)
    {
        _textView = textView;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of MvxConvertingTargetBinding
    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {            
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textView.Text))
        {
            _currentValue = (SummaryEnumeration)Convert.ToInt32(_textView.Text);

            SetTextViewBackground();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    void SetTextViewBackground()
    {
        switch (_currentValue)
        {
            case SummaryEnumeration.Easy:
                _textView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_circle_green);
                _textView.Text = string.Empty;

                break;
            case SummaryEnumeration.Medium:
                _textView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_circle_yellow);
                _textView.Text = string.Empty;

                break;
            case SummaryEnumeration.Difficult:
                _textView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_circle_red);
                _textView.Text = string.Empty;

                break;
            case SummaryEnumeration.None:
                _textView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_circle_none);
                _textView.Text = LocalizationConstants.Nothing;

                break;
        }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(bool); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

So you would probably end up with something like this in each fragment (fragment number in parenthesis):

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FilteredItems; CurrentFragment(1); ItemClick ItemSelected"
```

Where FilteredItems would be your Items filtered by which fragment you are in, filtered in the custom binding. In your case, my textview would be a MvxRecyclerView where you set the ItemsSource.